# Cumulative sum of factor variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a set of cumulative factor variables in R. My `df` has treatment dummies for 4 moments of time:

```
id t1 t2 t3 t4 
1   0  0  0  1 
2   1  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  1
4   0  1  0  0
5   1  0  0  0
```

What I want is a set of cumulative treatment variables (named tc in the following example) by time like this:

```
id tc1 tc2 tc3 tc4 
1   0  0  0  1 
2   1  1  1  1
3   0  0  0  1
4   0  1  1  1
5   1  1  1  1
```

I have tried the `cumsum` function, but I do not know how to handle this function for factor variables. Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to try the `matrixStats::rowCummaxs` function, but you will need to convert to a `matrix` first. Though, judging by your data structure, I would recommend working with a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame` in the first place

```
data1[-1] <- matrixStats::rowCummaxs(as.matrix(data1[-1]))
data1
#   id t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1  1  0  0  0  1
# 2  2  1  1  1  1
# 3  3  0  0  0  1
# 4  4  0  1  1  1
# 5  5  1  1  1  1
```

Or the blantant `apply` by row approach (which also convert to a `matrix`)

```
data1[-1] <- t(apply(data1[-1], 1, cummax))
```

Or as @joran implied - we could try the long/wide transformation

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(data1), 
           id = "id"
           )[, value := cummax(value),
             by = id], 
      id ~ variable)

#    id t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1:  1  0  0  0  1
# 2:  2  1  1  1  1
# 3:  3  0  0  0  1
# 4:  4  0  1  1  1
# 5:  5  1  1  1  1
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data1 %>%
  gather(variable, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = cummax(value)) %>%
  spread(variable, value)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# Groups: id [5]
# 
#      id    t1    t2    t3    t4
#   (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
# 1     1     0     0     0     1
# 2     2     1     1     1     1
# 3     3     0     0     0     1
# 4     4     0     1     1     1
# 5     5     1     1     1     1
```

Or an interesting alternative by @alexis_laz accumulating `pmax` per row using `Reduce`

```
data1[-1] <- Reduce(pmax, data1[-1], accumulate = TRUE)
data1
#   id t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1  1  0  0  0  1
# 2  2  1  1  1  1
# 3  3  0  0  0  1
# 4  4  0  1  1  1
# 5  5  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Probably the other major approach to this would be to melt/gather the data and actually have time as an explicit variable.

Comment: @joran, yeah I'll probably add that too. Thanks

Comment: Adding to the alternatives and seconding your matrix conversion comment: `tail(Reduce(pmax, DF[-1L], init = integer(nrow(DF)), accumulate = TRUE), -1L)` wrapped with `as.data.frame` or, better, `class<-` and `row.names<-`

Comment: @alexis_laz Wow, that's a nice one. You don't want to post it as your own?

Comment: I guess it's more suited in your answer with the all the instructive commentary, already, present.

Comment: @alexis_laz you don't really need `init` here, no? I've simplified your solution- see edit.

Answer (score 3):

`max.col` to the rescue:

```
df[-1][col(df[-1]) >= max.col(df[-1], ties.method="first")] <- 1
df

#  id t1 t2 t3 t4
#1  1  0  0  0  1
#2  2  1  1  1  1
#3  3  0  0  0  1
#4  4  0  1  1  1
#5  5  1  1  1  1
```

And some more detailed explanation of how this works:

```
col(df[-1])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
#[3,]    1    2    3    4
#[4,]    1    2    3    4
#[5,]    1    2    3    4

max.col(df[-1], ties.method="first")
#[1] 4 1 4 2 1

col(df[-1]) >= max.col(df[-1], ties.method="first")
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#[2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the code, it was very useful.